# JSON Reciever Endpoint

Tags: json

I'm wondering if it is possible to expose an SF endpoint to the internet that can receive JSON data. Its fairly simple to call out to an external service and retrieve data, but I am wanting an external service to call into my SF org whenever a transaction is completed in the external application. I'm wanting to parse this data and use it to create SF objects within the org. Is this possible? I feel like it is but all of my searching seems to yield results that pertain to retrieving data from endpoints rather than simply being a receiver. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this by creating @RESTRESOURCE

Links:

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_annotation_rest_resource.htm

Workbook:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apex_workbook/Content/apex_rest_1.htm

Comment: Eric, it'd be great if you had more than just a link only answer. That's preferred to help reduce the effect if link rot.

Comment: I agree with the above comment, however this answer was exactly what I needed!

Comment: @sfdcfox, point taken.

Comment: To prove the point the workbook link is now retired.